# How to separate the date to day, month and year; Also how convert it to date format using "tidyverse"

Tags: r, lubridate

[image]

I am new to R. How can I convert the date from the dataframe and separate it to "day", "month" and "year" using tidyverse.

[image]I did tried:

`df %>%  mutate(year = format(as.Date(date), "%Y")) %>%  mutate(month = format(as.Date(date), "%B")) %>%  mutate(date = format(as.Date(date), "%d"))`

It gives me a wrong output.

Comment: Do the date conversion first, then pull out the day, month and year using the appropriate functions from `library(lubridate)`. Something like `df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), day = day(date), month = month(date), year = year(date))`. We can't show you a working example because you used _pictures_ of code and data instead of code and data as text. We do ask that you don't do that when you post a question, because it makes your problem unreproducible.

Comment: @AllanCameron you are a savior! You saved me from hours of typing different codes just to make it work. Now, I know how to do it. The data I used are just for practicing purpose. I wanted to change a career that's why I am practicing and using R. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the chapter 'Dates and times' in R for Data Science as well: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html